# Disable error log file creation by php

Tags: php, unix, centos, cpanel

Whenever php content is accesed , File named `error_log` has been created with following contents repeatedly.

```
[25-Apr-2015 09:20:55 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/php_exif.dll' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/php_exif.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[25-Apr-2015 09:20:55 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/php_exif.dll' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/php_exif.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

I want to disable this file from creation.
I tried to `log_errors = Off` in `/usr/local/lib/php.ini` , Still this error_log is getting created.

Comment: How about just fixing your misconfigured php.ini instead of disabling the *entire error log*? You are effectively asking "how to shoot the messenger" instead of listening to what the messenger has to tell you. Fix what the messenger tells you.

Comment: Not sure but maybe there's a `log_errors = On` configuration that overwrites your `local/lib/php.ini`?